# How do I resize the text of bibliography entries without changing the heading (with BibTeX)?

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize

I'm using BibTeX to create my bibliography with the final command

```
\bibliographystyle{mn2e}
\bibligraphy{biblio}
```

I'd like the entries to be `footnotesize` so I use

```
{\footnotesize
\bibliographystyle{mn2e}
\bibligraphy{biblio}}
```

but this also resizes the heading "Bibliography". How do I resize the text but not the heading? I realize one workaround is to compile the bibliography with BibTeX and put the `\footnotesize` command in the `bibliography` block. But can I automate this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\footnotesize}
```